# Auto-complete with CodeMirrror

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, codemirror

I am trying to implement auto-complete using CodeMirror show-hint addon, specifically with sql-hint. I want it auto-complete as I type.

What I am doing right now is,

```
codemirror_editor.on("change", function(instance) {
    CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete(instance);
});
```

But the problem is, it completes words before I even type a single letter for a word. For example after space, it gives a long list of all possible tokens. I want it to show up only if some characters are typed. Can someone please help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved this, after [Marijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174164/auto-complete-with-codemirrror/26178800#26178800).

```
codemirror_editor.on("inputRead", function(instance) {
    if (instance.state.completionActive) {
        return;
    }
    var cur = instance.getCursor();
    var token = instance.getTokenAt(cur);
    var string = '';
    if (token.string.match(/^[.`\w@]\w*$/)) {
        string = token.string;
    }
    if (string.length > 0) {
        CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete(instance);
    }
});
```

This may be specific to SQL.

I am answering my own question to share the actual solution for the question.

Answer (score 2):

Before firing the autocomplete command, check whether the cursor is actually after 'some' (whatever 'some' means) letter characters. Also, do nothing when `instance.state.completionActive` is true, since that means there's already a completion popup open. Finally, you probably want to listen for the `"inputRead"` event instead of `"change"`, so that you don't trigger when a change is made to the document in a way that didn't involve the user typing.

Comment: Thanks. But there is slight problem with `"inputRead"`, It does not  continue auto-completing after backspace. How do I solve that using this approach?

Comment: That's a good point. You could use the `"change"` event after all, and check whether `change.origin` (`change` being the second argument passed to the event handler) is one of `"+input"` or `"+delete"` (typing or deleting actions).